# Multiple value key not adding, only remplacing in json file

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to write a program that send error message to json file when needed.

I wrote the following code:

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> erreur = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    public static             List<String> ErreurCycle = new ArrayList<String>();

if (condition) {
ErreurCycle.add("Le cycle est invalide");
            erreur.put("Erreur", ErreurCycle);
}

if (condition) {
 ErreurCycle.add("Le categorie est invalide");
                erreur.put("Erreur, "ErreurCycle");
}
```

Now, instead of adding "Le cycle est invalide" followed by "Le categorie est invalide" if need be, "Le categorie est invalide" is wrote 4 times and overwrites "Le cycle est invalide".

Is there a way to send a JSONArray to json file which contains multiples error message values for the same key error?

Answer (score 0):

In a map you have one value by index, you should put your error cycle in the list,

```
erreur.get("erreur").put("your message");
```

Comment: I forget to mention that with the json lib, you have to put  DiskFile.saveStringIntoFile("C:\\Users\\ej391004\\IdeaProjects\\untitled2\\src\\declarations.json", erreur.toString()) at the end of the method. Maybe this is where the erasing is done? Anything to change here?

Comment: try to erreur.put("Erreur, "ErreurCycle"); after all the if condition